# Localize the NAME of a string-array (and it's items)

Tags: java, android, xml

I've got a string-array

```
<string-array name="Color">
    <item>@string/red</item>
    <item>@string/green</item>
    <item>@string/purple</item>
</string-array>

<string name="red">red></string>
<string name="green">green></string>
<string name="purple">purple></string>
```

And I asses it in Java:

```
int id = R.array.Color;
String[] colors = getResources().getStringArray(id);
    
variantTextView.setText(getResources().getResourceEntryName(id));
ansA.setText(colors[0]);
ansB.setText(colors[1]);
ansC.setText(colors[2]);
```

1. How do I localize the NAME of this array?
2. Is it required to extract the strings as I've done it? Or is there a way to localize the entire array?

Comment: "I've got a string-array" -- please post code as text, not images.

Comment: Sorry. I've had problems with formatting it, so I decided to post a picture instead

Comment: @Aleksandr post it anyway, we'll format it for you if needed.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it next time

Comment: @Aleksandr no, please do it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I localize the NAME of this array?

You don't, any more than you localize a variable name in your Java/Kotlin code. If you want to display `Color` to users, have that to-be-displayed value as a separate string resource.

> Is it required to extract the strings as I've done it?

No.

> Or is there a way to localize the entire array?

Have two copies of your `Colors` `<string-array>`, each in the proper resource set based on language. Each `<string-array>` can then have `<item>` elements that contain the actual strings, not references to string resources. You might do this if you want the array to have a different order of elements (e.g., sorted alphabetically).